# Tikz script on Github returns no error but fail to render correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here are four Tikz scripts that i'm interested to reproduce:

- https://github.com/walmes/Tikz/blob/master/src/regressao_nao_linear.pgf
- https://github.com/walmes/Tikz/blob/master/src/modelo_binomial.pgf
- https://github.com/walmes/Tikz/blob/master/src/regressao_binomial.pgf
- [https://github.com/walmes/Tikz/blob/master/src/regressao_poisson.pgf](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/%7Ewalmes/Tikz/)

Take from: [http://www.leg.ufpr.br/~walmes/Tikz/](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/%7Ewalmes/Tikz/)

with their corresponding preamble:

https://github.com/walmes/Tikz/blob/master/src/TIKZ_PREAMBLE.pgs

However on two of my computers (Windows 10/MikTeX) and (Scientific Linux/LiveTeX), the scripts are compiled without error but the result is far from the expected one like illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image]

Sadly the author doesn't answer to my emails to help me to found the solution...

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thx

Comment: When I run the regressao_binomial plot for example I do get various warnings, first because there are `;` characters after `\def` which is not allowed (but harmless in this case), second there are warnings like `Package pgf Warning: Plot data file 'yourfile.x.table' not found. on input line 20`. This is because the plots use `function`, which means they are actually plotted using GNUplot. Therefore you need to make sure that you have 1. GNUplot installed and on the path and 2. compile with `-shell-escape`. When I do that I get the original plot without problems.

Comment: Note that for that particular plot you don't need the preamble from that Github repository at all, better leave it out as it adds a lot of unnecessary settings.

Comment: Thx Marijn for your feedback. I didn't know these prerequisites. The author of that LaTeX script should have say that in a comment in the preamble of the script.